# remove specific style from tailwind base

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

I have a project with tailwind and a (work in progress) UI library that we want to gradually migrate to.

I am importing the style on my `index.css` like this

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@import '@customPackage/ui-react/dist/style.css';
```

the problem is, tailwind base import some style that conflict with my customPackage styles :

[image]

`.ak2yjgf` is a style generated by the customPackage css, while `button, [type='button'], [type='reset'], [type='submit']` is by tailwind.

I know it's possible to add custom styling useing `@layers base` for tailwind, but this do not override the base style, it just add more. I would like to know if there is a way to override or remove the `base` import for `buttons` only.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Disabling [Tailwind preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#extending-preflight) is the closest thing that can help

```js
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

Then add their [preflight stylesheet](https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.0.24/src/css/preflight.css) and edit the section that's clashing with your styles.

Comment: This is useful for tracking down problematic base style rules when you don't know what can be causing the issue (comment/uncomment the rules as needed).

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in tailwind v3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding all of default styles inside of a .scss file within a class for example called .ql-wrapper{} and when I need somewhere to show the details that I added from a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your "@tailwind base" line with an import of your own tailwind base file. Looks like that:

```
@import "/src/preflight.css";
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

You can download Tailwinds base file from here:
https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.4.1/src/css/preflight.css

You can make as many changes you want in your preflight.css file

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this but I ended debugging with the solution above and once found the issue, I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package to remove that problematic style from the package.

Is not ideal, but been working for 2 years now.

Answer (score 0):

one good option i found is to turn off tailwind preflight and use custom pre-flight then you can remove styles you don't want

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

import the preflight manually from
https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.4.3/src/css/preflight.css

then add in your css

```css
@import preflight.css
```

then customize the preflight.css file.